# standard I/O library or Low-Level for unix / linux development

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

I'm brushing up on unix calls so this might seem a naive question (on vacation and just bored). I know that there's standard i/o in C but it always seems like the low-level calls (write, read, open) are used in practice for UNIX-like systems(just checked a couple of open-source projects). Is standard-io used in practice much? Are there cutoffs or specific reasons why the low-level api is used more? Or am I making a bad assumption from a few cherry-picked cases regarding low-level being more popular? I understand standard i/o is a C language element but seems like they achieve same thing and that low-level is used more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) library don't cover all the abilities available on Linux. In particular, [socket(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) and other low level functionalities (e.g. polling with [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) etc...) is not provided by `<stdio.h>` functions. However, `<stdio.h>` functions usually give [buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) which is practically very important for performance reasons. So calling [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) for every single byte would be very inefficient. Use [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) to flush `<stdio.h>` buffers.

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) for more.

In practice, mixing `<stdio.h>` functions and low-level syscalls (like [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) ...) with `<stdio.h>` functions is often (but not always) impractical. See also [fileno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html). So people may choose to code at the syscall level.

However, when  `<stdio.h>` functions are enough it is convenient to use them.

Also `<stdio.h>` is standardized in the [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) standard, but `write` etc... only in [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix) ....

Comment: thx, I really appreciate. I think you are kinda saying this but would it be fair to say that if it uses sockets, it (from a practical point of view) will always use syscall's and not the standard-io calls?

Comment: No, it really depends (notably of the familiarity of the software developer with `<stdio.h>` internals....)

Comment: thx, I slogged through Advanced Unix Programming and do a fair amount of shell / file stuff but things as fundamental as this, I sometimes don't get (def not fault of book or resources - just never done it full-time). If anything else, I'll just ask another question. thx again

Comment: Mixing stdio with bare system calls is strongly discouraged. stdio does extensive buffering and tracks it's own view of what is going on with the file. If you mess around with the file behind stdio's back, it *will* get confused. If you are lucky, your program then crashes, but sadly it will usually go on doing raving nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I tend to use stdio in 3 main areas:

(1) Where it is easy and practical to take advantage of stdio's buffering.

(2) text files where `fgets` and the like are more convenient to use than homegrown lower level functions which do the same thing.

(3) output formatting.  `fprintf` when it is practical; `sprintf` and `write` when it isn't.  I rarely use input formatting like `fscanf` but that might have more to do with the kinds of applications I encounter and when I do I usually try to wangle a way to write it in C++. (Totally personal preference.)

Thing is, in the "everything is (kind of) like a file" posix world, you tend to be using file descriptors for a lot of different calls so after awhile stdio becomes slightly cumbersome unless it offers something compelling.  Those things, for me, are listed above.

Comment: Also add `fread(3)` and `fwrite(3)` for binary I/O, and the whole set around `ftell(3)`. To switch back and forth, you have `fileno(3)` and `fdopen(3)`. So you can certainly use the stdio convenience functions over whatever file descriptor you've got.